# Disabling indentation for filenames without suffix

Tags: indentation, filetype

VIM's Wikia documentation states that you can disable indentation for certain filestypes by inserting the line

```
let b:did_indent = 1
```

in the file `~/.vim/indent/<filetype>.vim` where `<filetype>` is substituted by the filetype used.

What if I want this applied specifically to files without a suffix? What filetype does that constitute?

I have already tried using `autocmd FileType  let b:did_indent = 1` in my vimrc file, which doesn't work, as expected, since the blank space doesn't constitute *no suffix files*.

**Note.**

By indentation, I mean the behaviour that you get by having `set autoindent` inside your vimrc. I want this disabled for text-editing; in my case, files without a suffix.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by indent?  Files with no filetype set will have whatever the global default settings are, usually set in your vimrc

Comment: I mean automatic indentation which is set by `set autoindent`.

Comment: `autoindent` is by default off, so you must be setting it somewhere

Comment: What do you mean? If I have the line `set autoindent` in my vimrc --- which I intend to keep ---; this will enable automatic indentation by default indeed. But I want to disable it for filenames without a suffix. Problem: I don't know which filetype this constitutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files without a recognized filetype do not trigger the `FileType` autocmd at all.  Sometimes, but not always, this means files without an extension in their name.  Filetypes and suffixes are different things.  To be sure, you can do `:set filetype?` to see what the filetype is set to.  If this is an empty string, then no `FileType` autocmd can be used.

It seems to me what you want is the following:

1. Files with a `filetype` get `set autoindent`
2. Files without a `filetype` (i.e., plain text) get `set noautoindent`

Thus in your vimrc, you can use:

```
set noautoindent
augroup vimrc_indent
    au!
    autocmd FileType * set autoindent
augroup END
```

The first `set` sets the global option value, which applies to all buffers unless otherwise stated.  The second `set` sets the option for files with filetype.

See `:help autocmd` and `:help augroup` for the meaning of `augroup` and `au!`.  Briefly, this pattern of wrapping an `autocmd` with `augroup` (`vimrc_indent` is a completely arbitrary string) prevents multiple instances of the same `autocmd` from being installed when your vimrc is reloaded.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of `augroup` and `au!`? Also, what kind of keyword is `vimrc_indent`?

Comment: @MusséRedi It prevents those autocommands from being defined multiple times (and thus being run multiple times!) if you reload your vimrc. Steve Losh explains it pretty well [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html).